# ORDER condition not working in cakephp 3 TREE behavior

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp-3 tree behavior for Categories table. Here 'sequence_no' field are using to sorting sub-category list for a category. I am searching with a category_id to get all of his child category in ASCENDING order by 'sequence_no'. But order not working here. My code snippet and output here.

```
 $categoris = $this->Categories->find('children', ['for' => $id])
            ->find('threaded')
            ->contain('ParentCategories')
            ->order(['Categories.sequence_no' => 'ASC'])
            ->toArray();
```

- OUTPUT SAMPLE:

```
{
"status": "OK",
"result": {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 15,
            "store_id": 0,
            "uuid": null,
            "name": "cat-3",
            "parent_id": 3,
            "lft": 16,
            "rght": 17,
            "sequence_no": 2,
            "url": "cat-3",
            "layout_id": 0,
            "status": 1,
            "total": 0,
            "created": "2018-06-12T07:36:15+00:00",
            "modified": "2018-06-12T08:15:12+00:00",
            "parent_category": {
                "id": 3,
                "store_id": 2,
                "uuid": null,
                "name": "Pants",
                "parent_id": null,
                "lft": 15,
                "rght": 20,
                "sequence_no": null,
                "url": "pants",
                "layout_id": 0,
                "status": 1,
                "total": 0,
                "created": "2018-06-06T10:23:50+00:00",
                "modified": "2018-06-06T10:23:50+00:00"
            },
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "store_id": 0,
            "uuid": null,
            "name": "cat-4",
            "parent_id": 3,
            "lft": 18,
            "rght": 19,
            "sequence_no": 1,
            "url": "cat-4",
            "layout_id": 0,
            "status": 1,
            "total": 0,
            "created": "2018-06-12T07:36:34+00:00",
            "modified": "2018-06-12T08:15:12+00:00",
            "parent_category": {
                "id": 3,
                "store_id": 2,
                "uuid": null,
                "name": "Pants",
                "parent_id": null,
                "lft": 15,
                "rght": 20,
                "sequence_no": null,
                "url": "pants",
                "layout_id": 0,
                "status": 1,
                "total": 0,
                "created": "2018-06-06T10:23:50+00:00",
                "modified": "2018-06-06T10:23:50+00:00"
            },
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since findChildred finder add a `ORDER lft asc` clause to your query your order conditions will be appended to that

If you want to force your order you can do

```
->order(['Categories.sequence_no' => 'ASC'], true)
```

the second parameter in the `order()` method tells cake to overwrite the `ORDER BY` set before

see the manual, about the end of [**this**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data) paragraph